# How to submit form in a PHP file in WordPress?

Tags: forms

I have a simple form in my WordPress `footer.php`:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" name="contact" action="sub.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="my-name">Your first name</label>
        <input name="my-name" type="text" class="form-control" id="my-name" placeholder="Your first name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="my-email">and your email</label>
        <input name="my-email" type="text" class="form-control" id="my-email" placeholder="and your email">
    </div>
    <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Subscribe!">
</form>
```

I want to submit it to the file `sub.php`(which is in same directory), as you can see in the `action`. But even after trying too many solution I still am not able to get the task done.

Please point me to the simplest solution. Thanks

Comment: I see you tagged your question wordpress.com, is this question about the premium hosting service wordpress.com? Or was this tagged incorrectly? If it is, then the question would be closed as offtopic and you'll be directed to use the wordpress.com premium support and support forums

Comment: should I use wordpress.org?

Comment: you should use wordpress.com if you're on a wordpress.com hosted site ( then use the .com support channels ), and you should use  wordpress.org if your question is about the wordpress.org site. Otherwise you should use neither, it just confuses people who might be curious about your question

Comment: ok. I see an edit has been made to correct my mistake. I will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to submit it to the file sub.php(which is in same directory)

Don't do this. You should not have standalone PHP files that get queried via forms or AJAX etc, WordPress handles all the requests. By having a standalone file, you open a can of worms of security issues, and other problems ( you now have to bootstrap WP in your `sub.php` to use WP functions, which you shouldn't need to do if you did things correctly to begin with ).

Also keep in mind that you could easily just do `include( 'sub.php' )` in the form handling code, you don't have to completely rewrite the entire thing, just make sure it isn't possible to call it directly.

So:

- **Use the REST API** if you want to talk to your site with javascript, the `register_endpoint` function is all you need for this
- **Use the same page you're on, and an empty action** to handle forms. This handler can be in the same template before any output happens, it could be in `functions.php` or a plugin if it's redirecting

For example, lets say I have this form in my themes template, and if I enter a secret word I get a surprise here I can enter a word:

```php
<form method="post" action="">
    What's the Secret Word? <input type="text" name="toms_secret_word" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I now have a form that submits to the same page, with a value I can check for, e.g.:

```php
if ( isset( $_POST['toms_secret_word'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['toms_secret_word'] === 'open sesame' ) {
        echo "Correct!";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect! Try again"
        // display the form
    }
} else {
    //... display the form
}
```

I'd advise moving the form into a file, that way you can do `get_template_part( 'secretwordform' );` and have a `secretwordform.php`, and even a `secretwordform-success.php` and `secretwordform-incorrect.php`.

As a bonus, you can use hidden inputs and have multi-page forms. This way you have a hidden input saying which page is next, and hidden inputs for the items on other pages.